# ASMX web service deployment package for Windows Azure

Tags: azure, asmx, setup-deployment

I have one ASMX Web Service (ASP.Net, not WCF)) that is being used by many of clients.

Now I want to create deployment package of this web service so that I can distribute it to the client and they can deploy it on their Azure cloud. Just to clarify, this web service is a product that can be used by different people for their own data.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: When ever i have tried to create a setup proj for web service some thing went wrong. So i do it with the traditional manual way. (That's personal experience and not the solution)

Comment: How did you do that then? Please let me know.

Comment: By the manual way. Create virtual directory on client's iis and so on.